# Singly-Linked List: Insert node between 2 nodes

Tags: java, loops, linked-list, nodes, insertion

I am working on a project to simulate memory segments arriving and departing virtual memory. When a *segment* departs, or memory is not occupied, it becomes a *hole.*

---

**Constraints:**

- "head" node must always point to the lowest address in memory.

---

**Problem:** I am getting caught in a circular loop when inserting a node between 2 nodes. I have been trying to hold a "previous" and "current" node, unsuccessfully.
Instead of the list being this: `Node0 -> Node1 -> Node2` 
it is showing `Node0 ->Node2`, where Node1 is the node being inserted.

*Output:*
[image: Location - Size - Time to depart]

| Location | Size | Time to depart |

---

**Attempt at solution:** I created a previous and current node to insert the node between. The search must begin at the node that was last place; `lastPlacement`. I have commented above the section thet I believe triggers the error.
 **Entire code placed below, error is occurring in *place method*.**

**Test file to use while running:**

```
N
R 1000 5 100 80 10000
P
E
```

---

```
/********************************************************************************
 *  @author       Evan Bechtol (ecb120030)
 *                <h1>Project: Memory Segmentation Simulation</h1>
 *                <p>Simulation of arrivals/departures/placements of segments in a 
 *                segmented virtual memory, through the use of a linked-list. Implements a 
 *                next-fit policy. Constraints: There can never be neighboring holes.</p>
 *  @since        2015-2-13
 *  @see          http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-to-bubble-sort
 *  @see          http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf
 *  @see          http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Singly-linked_list/Removal
 *  @see          http://crunchify.com/a-simple-singly-linked-list-implementation-in-java/
 *  
 ********************************************************************************/

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Creates nodes to be used as data containers in the Memory class
 */
class Node {
    boolean segment;        // Equals false if this Node represents a hole
    int     location;       // Position in memory of first byte
    int     size;           // Size that node occupies
    int     timeToDepart;   // Only valid when this Node represents a segment
    Node    next;

    /** 
     * Constructor for generating a segment in memory
     * 
     * @param   locn        location of node to be created 
     * @param   sz          size of node to be created
     * @param   endOfLife   the timeOfDay node is to depart
     * @param   nxt         specifies the next node to reference in the list
     */
    Node (int locn, int sz, int endOfLife, Node nxt) {
        segment      = true;
        location     = locn;
        size         = sz;
        timeToDepart = endOfLife;
        next         = nxt;
    }

    /** 
     * Constructor for a hole   
     * 
     * @param   locn    location of hole to be created
     * @param   sz      size of hole to be created
     * @param   nxt     reference to next node in the list
     */
    Node (int locn, int sz, Node nxt) {
        segment     = false;
        location    = locn;
        size        = sz;
        next        = nxt;
    }
} // End Node class

/**
 *  Creates a linked-list of ndoes to simulate virtual memory segments and holes
 */
class Memory {
    private static int memorySize;  // Defines the total size for the memory
    Node head;                      // Refers to first node in memory
    Node lastPlacement;             // Refers to the last node that was placed, or hole if the last placed segment is removed

    /**
     * Constructor for Memory, generates a single hole Node of the given size   
     * 
     * @param   size    initial size of memory object
     */
    Memory (int size) {
            memorySize = size;
            Node n = new Node (0, memorySize, null);
            lastPlacement = head = n;
    }

    /** 
     *  Attempts to place a request using the Next Fit Policy. Returns false if there
     *  isn't a hole big enough. Prints a confirmation if placed; return true   
     *  
     *  @param      size        size of placement to be made
     *  @param      timeOfDay   the time at which the placement is being made
     *  @param      lifeTime    how long the segment is to remain in memory
     *  @param      verbose     specifies if extra placement information is to be given
     *  @return     boolean:    returns true if the placement was successful
     */
    boolean place (int size, int timeOfDay, int lifeTime, boolean verbose) {

        // If the list is empty, we can place as head node
        if (isEmpty()) {
            Node current = new Node (0, size, 0, null);
            lastPlacement = head = current;
            return true;
        }
        // There are nodes in the list
        else {
            Node current = lastPlacement; // We start searching for a hole at our lastPlacement
            Node previous = head;
            // While there are still nodes to reverse, keep looking
            while (current != null) {

                // If we are looking at a hole and it is equal to, or larger than our required size
                if ((!current.segment) && (current.size >= size)) {

                    // Hole is EXACT size required
                    if (current.size == size) {
                        current.segment = true;
                        current.timeToDepart = timeOfDay + lifeTime;
                    }
                    // Hole is larger than our size required
                    else {
                        Node newNode = new Node (current.location, size, timeOfDay + lifeTime, current); //timeOfDay + lifeTime = timeToDepart

                        current.location += size + 1;
                        current.size -= size;
                        lastPlacement = newNode;
                        previous.next = newNode;

                        if (newNode.location == 0) {
                            head = newNode;
                        }
                    }
                    /*  newNode.segment     = true;
                        current.next  = newNode;
                        current.size  = current.size - size; // Adjust size of hole after placing segment
                        lastPlacement = newNode;*/

                        // If verbose == true, print the confirmation
                        if (verbose) {
                            System.out.println ("Segment at location: " + lastPlacement.location + "\twith size: " + lastPlacement.size + "\tdeparts at: " + lastPlacement.timeToDepart);
                        }
                        return true;
                }
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            } // End while

            current = head; // To traverse from start of list

            //While there are still nodes to reverse, keep looking
            while (current != lastPlacement) {
                // If we are looking at a hole
                if ((!current.segment) && (current.size >= size)) {

                    // Hole is EXACT size required
                    if (current.size == size) {
                        current.segment = true;
                        current.timeToDepart = timeOfDay + lifeTime;
                    }
                    // Hole is larger than our size required
                    else {

                    // If the hole is larger or equal to the size we need
                        Node newNode = new Node (current.location, size, timeOfDay + lifeTime, current); //timeOfDay + lifeTime = timeToDepart

                        current.location += size + 1;
                        current.size -= size;
                        lastPlacement = newNode;
                        previous.next = newNode;

                        if (newNode.location == 0) {
                            head = newNode;
                        }
                    }
                    /*  newNode.segment     = true;
                        current.next  = newNode;
                        current.size  = current.size - size;
                        lastPlacement = newNode;*/

                        // If verbose == true, print the confirmation
                        if (verbose) {
                            System.out.println ("Placed segment at location: " + lastPlacement.location + "\twith size: " + lastPlacement.size + "\tdeparts at: " + lastPlacement.timeToDepart);
                        }
                        return true;
                }
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            } // End while
        }
        // If we reach this point, segment could not be placed
        return false;
    }

    /**
     *  Remove segments from the list, which are ready to depart.
     *  <p>Checks the following conditions:<ul><li>
     *      1) Head is segment and ready to depart
     *      2) Current is segment and ready to depart
     *      3) Previous is hole, current is hole
     *      4) We are combining the node containing last placement, with another node</li></ul></p>
     *  
     *  @param  timeOfDay   time at which the removal is being done
     */
    void removeSegmentsDueToDepart (int timeOfDay) {

        // Case 1: Head is segment and ready to depart
        if ((head.segment) && (head.timeToDepart <= timeOfDay)) {
            head.segment = false; // Allow node to become a hole
            //System.out.println ("Case 1.");
        }

        // Create reference to head node
        Node previous = head;

        // Begin iterating on list from 2nd node
        while (previous.next != null) {
            //Use this as our current position
            Node current = previous.next;  

            // Case 2: Current is segment and ready to depart
            if ((current.segment) && (current.timeToDepart <= timeOfDay)) {
                //Combine
                current.segment = false;
                //System.out.println ("Case 2.");

            }

            // Case 3: previous is hole, current is hole
            if ((!previous.segment) && (!current.segment)) {
                // Case 4: We are combining the node containing last placement, with another node
                if (current == lastPlacement) {
                    // Set last placement to the node to be combined to
                    lastPlacement = previous;
                    //System.out.println ("Case 4.");
                }
                // Combine
                previous.size += current.size;
                previous.next = current.next;
            }
            // Else we adjust our position.
            else {
                previous = current;
            }
        } // End while
    }

    /** 
     * Print a 3-column tab-separated list of all segments in Memory.
     * Displayed in ascending order of location.    
     */
    void printLayout() {
        Node current;

        // Print the sorted array of nodes
        for (current = head; current != null; current = current.next) {
            System.out.println (current.location + "\t" + current.size + "\t" + current.timeToDepart);
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Determines the empty or occupied state of the list
     * 
     * @return  Returns true if list is empty
     * @return  Returns false if nodes are in the list
     */ 
    public boolean isEmpty () {
        if (head == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
} // End Memory class


/**
 * Class to test Memory and Node classes. Accepts file-redirection from commandline by using the 
 * scanner with System.in, can also accept file input by using scanner with new File        
 */
public class EVBEP1 {

    /**
     * Used to test implementation of Memory and Node objects. Processes commands received through
     * either the commandline or file-input.
     * 
     * @param   args                   Standard parameter for parsing commands received
     * @throws  FileNotFoundException  If file is unable to be located, exception is thrown 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Used for accepting command line arguments
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        // Used for testing purposes
        Scanner sc          = new Scanner(new File("p115sd5.txt"));
        String line         = "";
        boolean done        = false;
        Memory memory       = new Memory(0); // Memory object
        int  timeOfDay      = 0;             // Simulated wall clock, begins with value zero
        int  placements     = 0;             // Number of placements completed, begins with value zero
        long totalSpaceTime = 0;             // Sum of placed segmentSize(i) x segmentLifetime(i)       
        float meanOccupancy = 0;

        // Loop runs as long as done != true
        while (!done) {
            line = sc.nextLine();               // Store data gathered from file into String
            String [] tokens = line.split(" "); // Split the string using space as delimiter

            // Switch for processing commands received
            switch (tokens[0]) {

            // Print name followed by newline
            case "N": {
                    System.out.println("Evan Clay Bechtol");
                    break;
                }

            // Create a memory object of size s
            case "C": {
                    memory = new Memory(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1])); // Create a new Memory object
                    break;
                }

            // End of data file, print newline and exit
            case "E": {
                    System.out.println();
                    done = true;    // Break the loop, end the program
                    break;
                }

            // Add segment of size 'u' and lifetime 'v' and print confirmation record
            case "A": {
                    int size = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                    int lifeTime = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                    timeOfDay++;

                    memory.removeSegmentsDueToDepart(timeOfDay);

                    // Boolean controls whether confirmation is printed.
                    while (!memory.place(size, timeOfDay, lifeTime, true)) {
                        timeOfDay++;
                        memory.removeSegmentsDueToDepart(timeOfDay);
                        } // End while
                    placements++;

                    // Print confirmation message
                    System.out.printf("Segment of size %4d", size);
                    System.out.printf("\tplaced at time %4d", timeOfDay);
                    System.out.printf("\tat location %4d", memory.lastPlacement.location);
                    System.out.printf("\tdeparts at %4d", memory.lastPlacement.timeToDepart);
                    System.out.println();
                    break;  
                }

            // Print the current segments in the list
            case "P": {
                    System.out.println ();
                    memory.printLayout();
                    break;
                }

            case "R": {
                    int size = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]); // Size
                    memory = new Memory(size);
                    int minSegSize = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);   // Minimum seg. size
                    int maxSegSize = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);   // Maximum seg. size
                    int maxLifeTime = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);  // Maximum lifetime of segs.
                    int numSegs = Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]);      // Number of segs. to simulate
                    timeOfDay = 0;
                    placements = 0;
                    Random ran = new Random (); // "Random" number generator
                    Scanner n = new Scanner (System.in);
                    while (placements < numSegs) {
                        //System.out.println ("Press any key to iterate.. Placements made: " + placements);
                        memory.printLayout();
                        //System.out.println ("Loc: " + memory.lastPlacement.location + "\tSize: " + memory.lastPlacement.size + "\tdeparts at: " + memory.lastPlacement.timeToDepart);
                        /*if( memory.lastPlacement.next != null) {
                            System.out.println ("Next)" + " Loc: " + memory.lastPlacement.next.location + "\tSize: " + memory.lastPlacement.next.size + "\tdeparts at: " + memory.lastPlacement.next.timeToDepart);
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println ("Next = null");
                        }*/
                        //n.nextLine();

                        timeOfDay++;
                        memory.removeSegmentsDueToDepart(timeOfDay);
                        int newSegSize = minSegSize + ran.nextInt(maxSegSize - minSegSize + 1);
                        int newSegLifetime = 1 + ran.nextInt(maxLifeTime);
                        totalSpaceTime += newSegSize * newSegLifetime;

                        while (!memory.place(newSegSize, timeOfDay, newSegLifetime, false)) {
                            timeOfDay++;
                            memory.removeSegmentsDueToDepart(timeOfDay);
                        } // End while
                        placements++;
                    } // End while

                    // Print final summary of execution
                    meanOccupancy = totalSpaceTime / (timeOfDay);
                    System.out.printf ("Number of placements made =  %6d", placements);
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.printf ("Mean occupancy of memory  = %8.2f", meanOccupancy);
                    System.out.println();
                    n.close();
                    break;
                }
            } // End switch
        } // End while
        sc.close();
    } // End main
} // End EVBEP1 class
```

Comment: What is size and location here.? Whats the difference?

Comment: Also, what is lastPlacement? The end of the list, or the last place you inserted?

Comment: @Aify lastPlacement = last placed node.

Comment: @Kode size = size of segement or hole

location = physical location in memory

Comment: You should do newNode.next = current; previous.next = newNode; previous = newNode; current = newNode.next. Looking at your Node object what do you do with current when you instantiate the object?

Comment: @Kode  I updated my post, please see bottom edit.  Current should just be moved over one place, unless it is the EXACT size that the node requires.

I tried your fix, but I still get stuck in the loop :(

Comment: Show complete code, as it is now there is too much left to guess; e.g. what state your new Node() is in after creation, starting with `current = lastPlacement` looks *really suspicious* (as does `current.location += size + 1`) and how can you tell if the list wasn't already messed up elsewhere? The first thing one does in this case is step through in the debugger and pay attention that what happens is what is supposed to happen. If that proves too unwieldy, write a consistency checking method and have list consistency checked at appropiate sites.

Comment: @Durandal I have been using the debugger to try and figure out how to resolve the problem, I know where the problem occurs and what is happening, but now how to fix it. I just updated my code with the entire code for the question.

Comment: @Durandal Ok, through more debugging I found the problem.... When I place the 2nd node, the references become circular. newNode.next = current     and current.next = newNode.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `current.location += size + 1` should be without +1 (if you take away 10 from a node at location 0, the next free byte is at 10, not at 11), and as far as I gather you indend to start the search at the location last allocated. In that case a single linked, one end terminated list, is not the data structure to use (your search for free space cannot reach anywhere before lastPlacement).

Comment: @Durandal Location is really arbitrary and has nothing to do with the search or the actual node. The problem is that each of the nodes is pointing back at one another and I can't figure out how to have them just point down the line.

Comment: One point where your nodes can go wrong is that your loop in place() does not ensure to adhere to the most basic constraint: `previous.next == current`. You initialize Memory as `head = lastPlacement = new Node()`, meaning the constraint is already violated by improper initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adjusting the place method to the following:

```
boolean place (int size, int timeOfDay, int lifeTime, boolean verbose) {

    // If the list is empty, we can place as head node
    if (isEmpty()) {
        Node current = new Node (0, size, -1, null);
        lastPlacement = head = current;
        return true;
    }
    // There are nodes in the list
    else {
        Node current = lastPlacement; //We start searching for a hole at our lastPlacement

        //While there are still nodes to reverse, keep looking
        while (current != null) {
            // If we are looking at a hole
            if (!current.segment && current.timeToDepart <= timeOfDay) {

                if (current.size == size) {
                    current.segment = true;
                    current.timeToDepart = timeOfDay + lifeTime;
                }
                // If the hole is larger or equal to the size we need
                if (current.size > size) {
                    Node n = new Node (current.location, size, timeOfDay + lifeTime, current.next); //timeOfDay + lifeTime = timeToDepart
                    n.segment = true;
                    current.next = n;
                    current.size = current.size - size; // Adjust size of hole after placing segment
                    lastPlacement = current = n;

                    // If verbose == true, print the confirmation
                    if (verbose) {
                        System.out.println ("Segment at location: " + lastPlacement.location + "\twith size: " + lastPlacement.size + "\tdeparts at: " + lastPlacement.timeToDepart);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            current = current.next;
        } // End while

        current = this.head; // To traverse from start of list

        //While there are still nodes to reverse, keep looking
        while (current != lastPlacement) {
            // If we are looking at a hole
            if (!current.segment && current.timeToDepart <= timeOfDay) {

                if (current.size == size) {
                    current.segment = true;
                    current.timeToDepart = timeOfDay + lifeTime;
                }
                // If the hole is larger or equal to the size we need
                if (current.size > size) {
                    Node n = new Node (current.location + size, size, timeOfDay + lifeTime, current.next); //timeOfDay + lifeTime = timeToDepart
                    n.segment = true;
                    current.next = n;
                    current.size = current.size - size;
                    lastPlacement = current =  n;

                    // If verbose == true, print the confirmation
                    if (verbose) {
                        System.out.println ("Segment at location: " + lastPlacement.location + "\twith size: " + lastPlacement.size + "\tdeparts at: " + lastPlacement.timeToDepart);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            current = current.next;
        } // End while
    }
    // If we reach this point, segment could not be placed
    return false;
}
```